# Excel, how to have grouped TRIMMEAN

Tags: excel, excel-formula, statistics, mean

Hi i have dynamic data updated from remote every day of that type

| state | city | id | number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| s1 | c1 | i1 | 45 |
| s1 | c1 | i2 | 2 |
| s1 | c2 | i3 | 12 |
| s2 | c1 | i4 | 23 |
| s2 | c4 | i5 | 45 |

i need a result set with this structure

| state | city | avg |
| --- | --- | --- |

i try with pivot but `TRIMMEAN()` is not available as group function

i cannot add column so source data since is imported from external web sites and row number change each time

result set will be source for other sheet with other calculation so every solution must have static column and be able to manage dynamic rows generated from input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps using `GROUPBY()` or `PIVOTBY()` you can accomplish the output returned with `TRIMMEAN()` function with a `LAMBDA()` construct to iterate the function, here are the solutions you can follow, if you are presently using `MS365` with the `Beta Channel` Enabled.

• Using `GROUPBY()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=GROUPBY(A2:B6,D2:D6,LAMBDA(x,TRIMMEAN(x,0.2)),0,0)
```

---

• Or, Using `PIVOTBY()`

```
=PIVOTBY(A2:B6,,D2:D6,LAMBDA(x,TRIMMEAN(x,0.2)),0,0)
```

---

• *MSFT Documentations* --> **[TRIMMEAN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/trimmean-function-d90c9878-a119-4746-88fa-63d988f511d3)**

---

Also, to get the output generated dynamically even when new data is added to the source I had prefer using `Structured References` aka `Tables` that way, it does not iterates unwanted blank rows for data manipulations, however, if one is not fond of `Structured References` may use as follows.

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _lastRow, MATCH(2^2,1/(A:A<>"")),
     _data, A2:INDEX(A:D,_lastRow,),
     GROUPBY(TAKE(_data,,2),TAKE(_data,,-1),LAMBDA(x,TRIMMEAN(x,0.2)),0,0))
```

---

• Using `Tables` its more cleaner and simpler.

[image]

---

```
=GROUPBY(TAKE(SourceTbl,,2),TAKE(SourceTbl,,-1),LAMBDA(x,TRIMMEAN(x,0.2)),0,0)
```

---

Comment: Oh! I am not on beta channel and missed `GROUPBY()` and `PIVOTBY()` functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on ***M365*** then could try-

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(A2:B6),y,MAP(CHOOSECOLS(x,1),CHOOSECOLS(x,2),LAMBDA(a,b,AVERAGEIFS(D2:D6,A2:A6,a,B2:B6,b))),HSTACK(x,y))
```

For continuous coming data, you can make it dynamic.

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(A2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B))),
y,MAP(CHOOSECOLS(x,1),CHOOSECOLS(x,2),LAMBDA(st,ct,AVERAGEIFS(D:D,A:A,st,B:B,ct))),
HSTACK(x,y))
```

[image]